# Processing data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

I need to make some calculations on a data set and display that information in a progress bar. I'm trying to decide if I should do these calculations in Angular or in my REST API.

I have "Levels" associated with users. For example - if a user has completed Level 3, they have completed that task. Now say I have 20 users. I would have a progress bar where the max (100%) would be 20/20, and the min would be 0/20. For each user that has completed Level 3, they would count as completed for that particular progress bar (1/20).

I might have 5 different progress bars for different sections, where the 1st is level 3 complete, the second is level 8 complete, etc.

Right now my API is currently returning the levels for each user. So I might get 
something like this:

```
{User 1:
  Section 1: 
    Level 1:
      (relevant data...)
    Level 3:
      (relevant data...)

  Section 2:
    Level 4:
      (relevant data...)
...}
```

10 user objects with each having Level 3, Level 8, etc. Would it be better to do the calculations on the server, with it returning a hash of the calculated data? i.e.

```
User 1:{
  Section 1: Complete,
  Section 2: In Progress,
  Section 3: Complete
}
User 2:{...}
```

Or would it be better to take the raw data and calculate if section 1 is complete through an Angular filter?

Comment: How do you measure 'better'?

Comment: Better practice mostly, so I don't run into unforseen issues down the road. I'm not sure if putting that heavy of a calculation at a URL endpoint is very RESTful (although I might be wrong), but I'm also not sure if you're supposed to do that much data processing with angular either

Comment: Unless you have thousands of users, or some ridiculously complicated calculations, any difference between doing it on the client or the server is pretty much nil. I'm not sure if it's best RESTful practice but I would do it on the server myself and keep the client lean.